# Second Relation not read in Laravel when use with two times

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have a relationship between SalesTransaction and SalesTransactionDetail,
then the SalesTransactionDetailhas Relation with Produk and JenisMuatan Table.

but when i call JenisMuatan in blade.php, it give errors. the error is there is no JenisMuatan->name, but Produk->name is ok, nothing error with Produk.

here is my code :

```
$sales = SalesTransaction::with('Customer')->with('User')->latest()->get();
        foreach ($sales as $item) {
            $item['detail'] = SalesTransactionDetail::where('sales_transaction_id', $item->id)->with('Produk')->with('JenisMuatan')->get();
        }
```

and this is how i implement in view

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < $sales->count(); $i++)
            @for ($j = 0; $j < $sales[$i]->detail->count(); $j++)
                <tr>
                    @if ($sales[$i]->detail->count() > 1)
                        @if ($j == 0)
                            <td style="text-align: center; height: 20;"
                                rowspan="{{ $j == 0 ? $sales[$i]->detail->count() : 1 }}">
                                {{ $j > 0 ? '' : $i + 1 }}</td>
                            <td style="text-align: left; height: 20;"
                                rowspan="{{ $j == 0 ? $sales[$i]->detail->count() : 1 }}">
                                {{ $j > 0 ? '' : "'" . $sales[$i]->invoice_number }}</td>
                            <td style="text-align: left; height: 20;"
                                rowspan="{{ $j == 0 ? $sales[$i]->detail->count() : 1 }}">
                                {{ ($j > 0 ? '' : $sales[$i]->customer_id == null) ? 'Cash' : 'Deposit : ' . $sales[$i]->customer->name }}
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: right; height: 20;"
                                rowspan="{{ $j == 0 ? $sales[$i]->detail->count() : 1 }}">
                                {{ $j > 0 ? '' : $sales[$i]->total_harga }}</td>
                        @endif
                    @endif
                    @if ($sales[$i]->detail->count() <= 1)
                        <td style="text-align: center; height: 20;">{{ $i + 1 }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: left; height: 20;">{{ "'" . $sales[$i]->invoice_number }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: left; height: 20;">
                            {{ $sales[$i]->customer_id == null ? 'Cash' : 'Deposit : ' . $sales[$i]->customer->name }}
                        </td>

                        <td style="text-align: right; height: 20;"
                            rowspan="{{ $j == 0 ? $sales[$i]->detail->count() : 1 }}">
                            {{ $j > 0 ? '' :  $sales[$i]->total_harga }}</td>
                    @endif
                    <td style="text-align: left; height: 20;">
                        {{ $sales[$i]->detail[$j]->produk->name }}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: left; height: 20;">
                        {{ $sales[$i]->detail[$j]->jenis_muatan->name }}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; height: 20;">
                        {{ $sales[$i]->detail[$j]->total_harga }}</td>

                        @if ($sales[$i]->detail->count() > 1)
                        @if ($j == 0)
                            <td style="text-align: left; height: 20;"
                                rowspan="{{ $j == 0 ? $sales[$i]->detail->count() : 1 }}">
                                {{ $j > 0 ? '' : "'" . $sales[$i]->created_at }}</td>
                        @endif
                    @endif
                    @if ($sales[$i]->detail->count() <= 1)
                        <td style="text-align: left; height: 20;"
                            rowspan="{{ $j == 0 ? $sales[$i]->detail->count() : 1 }}">
                            {{ $j > 0 ? '' : "'" . $sales[$i]->created_at }}</td>
                    @endif
                </tr>
            @endfor
        @endfor
```

here is the error image
[image]

thanks before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solve this problem. this problem maybe usually happen to the beginner in laravel like me.
so i will answer this question, maybe someone who has the same problem like this, can solve their problem.

in this app before i solve the problem, i call the relation name use table names such jenis_muatan, produk. and it make an error if the relation in model that use different style of function name.

in model, i use JenisMuatan. so, it is different with table name, JenisMuatan to jenis_muatan. then, if i call the name use jenis_muatan, it give error. but if it calls with JenisMuatan, it works perfectly.

```
jenis_muatan->name // error
JenisMuatan->name //work
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description you say that "TransactionDetail has Relation with Produk and JenisMuatan Table" but in your code you try to get the relation from SalesTransactionDetail.

Try to change this line :

```
 $item['detail'] = SalesTransactionDetail::where('sales_transaction_id', $item->id)->with('Produk')->with('JenisMuatan')->get();
```

to that:

```
 $item['detail'] = TransactionDetail::where('sales_transaction_id', $item->id)->with('Produk')->with('JenisMuatan')->get();
```

Or if you intented to fetch the SalesTransactionDetail you can fetch 2nd levelrelation ships like this:

```
$item['detail'] = SalesTransactionDetail::where('sales_transaction_id', $item->id)->with('TransactionDetail.Produk')->with('TransactionDetail.JenisMuatan')->get();
```

Comment: the real table name is SalesTransactionDetail, not TransactionDetail

Comment: Hi, ip udpated my answer :) hope it helps

Comment: Call to undefined relationship [SalesTransactionDetail] on model [App\Models\SalesTransactionDetail].

Comment: coudl you update your question with the relationships defined in SalesTransactionDetail, and in TransactionDetail?

Comment: i have update the question

Comment: I mean could you put how you define the relations to salestransactiondetail and transactiondetail? on you model?

Comment: i have edit it again, and i put in the view code

Comment: for the model, it only hasmany and belongsto

Comment: I still cannot see the relation implementation on the model

Answer (score 0):

you are calling two methods that's why it's not loading the second relation.

The proper way to eager load multiple relations is by adding commas, let's take an eye on given below.

```
$sales = SalesTransaction::with('Customer', 'User')->latest()->get();
```

Comment: still has same error using <td style="text-align: left; height: 20;">
                        {{ $sales[$i]->detail[$j]->jenis_muatan->name }}</td>

Comment: you are doing some mistake when pulling the key, just dd($sales) and check how it's wrapping the collection, then retrieve it.